# Sumar las horas de dos campos tipo time MySQL

Tags: mysql

quiero pedir su ayuda, ya que estoy haciendo un programa de bitácoras el cual me permite registrar las actividades diarias de cada usuario. lo que quiero hacer ahora es realizar una consulta donde pueda sumar las horas laboradas por día, he intentado hacer varias consultas pero algunas solo me devuelven 1 y otras solo me suman las horas de 1 fila, quisiera que me ayudaran a poder realizar esta consulta, estare muy agradecido. les comparto los datos.

Los campos que quiero sumar son tipo **time**.
El nombre de los campos es **inicio** y **fin**.
Esta es la consulta que mas se ha acercado.

```
SELECT CONCAT( HOUR(SUM(TIMEDIFF(inicio, fin))), ':',MINUTE(SUM(TIMEDIFF(inicio, fin)))) FROM bitacoras_sistemas WHERE fecha = '2019-05-01'
```

Esta consulta solo me suma 1 fila
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
si solo suma la fila 1 me lo suma bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si quiero  sumar la fila 2 y 3 no lo hace correctamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaria muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba pasando a segundos esa diferencia, que calculas con `TIMEDIFF()`, utilizando `TIME_TO_SEC()`, suma, y después ya vuelves a convertirlo a formato legible con `SEC_TO_TIME()`:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(fin,inicio)))
  ) total FROM bitacoras_sistemas;
```

Sumando directamente en formato `TIME`, ya ves que no funciona.

Adjunto dataset abreviado en formato SQL para facilitar las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE bitacoras_sistemas(
  inicio time,
  fin time
  );
INSERT INTO bitacoras_sistemas (inicio, fin) VALUES
  ('8:30','9:00'),
  ('22:00','22:30'),
  ('12:30','13:00');
```

Comment: Me funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias por apoyarme.

Comment: otra pregunta, como podria hacer este mismo procedimiento si solo tengo los campos **inicio** y **fin**, donde ambos son de tipo **datetime**, y los valores se insertan de la siguiente manera **2019-04-30 14:00:00** esto para ambos campos. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Interesante... plantea otra pregunta, adaptando el dataset para que también incluya las fechas, y vamos a ver si conseguimos dar con ello. Si inicio y fin están en el mismo día, la solución es trivial, no tenemos más que prescindir de la fecha con un `TIME()`. Lo que tendría que probar es con fechas diferentes... Y mira, sí, funciona: `SELECT TIMEDIFF('2019-04-05 0:05','2019-04-04 23:50');` da perfectamente 15 minutos :)

Comment: Lo hice de la misma forma solo le agregue un between para el campo inicio y también para el fin, me quedó de esta manera y me funciono perfecto `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(fin,inicio))) ) total 
FROM bitacoras_sistemas WHERE id = "JULIOCOL" 
AND inicio BETWEEN '2019-04-30' AND '2019-05-06'
AND fin BETWEEN '2019-04-30' AND '2019-05-06'`